# How can I get file as not corrupted after downloading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`handleDownload()` function is added to a button as event handler(onclick) so that user can download the file. User is able to download but gets corrupted file. how can we prevent file corruption ?

```
function handleDownload(){  
    const domain = window.location.origin;
    const url =`${domain}/images/athar.pdf`
    fetch(url).
    then(response=>response.blob()).
    then(blob=>{
      const blobURL= window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([blob]))

      const filename = 'athar.pdf'
      const aTag  = document.createElement('a')
      aTag.href=blobURL
      aTag.setAttribute('download',filename)
    
      document.body.appendChild(aTag)
      aTag.click()
      aTag.remove()
      }).
    catch(e=>console.log(e))

            
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're already getting response as a blob, no need to convert it to blob again, so try removing that part.

Try replacing:

```
 const blobURL= window.URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([blob]))
```

with this:

```
const blobURL= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: that means there are problems with the source file, can you access `const url =\`${domain}/images/athar.pdf\``, try comparing the file size, is the file size of the downloaded file the same or different, also try logging `blob`, see what it says for `type`, maybe try some other file etc.